# ggplot2 increase font size of output labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, size, axis-labels

I am working with ggplot2 to create plots and I want to increase the size of the labels from the output, so not the labels added manually.

I tried to use cex put this works only partially as it only increases the count size in the plot but not the x or y labels

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Gender, fill = gen))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#40E0D0","#DE3163"))+
  labs(y="All", fill ="Gender:")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,550,50))+
  ggtitle("Gender")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size =20, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", angle = 90))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face="bold"), legend.position = "bottom")+
  geom_text(aes(label=stat(count), cex = 6), stat = "count",
            position=position_dodge(width = 1),vjust= -0.2, cex = 6)+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20))
``
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: `+ theme(text = element_text(size = 20))` increases the text size of all text elements to size=20.